# Get Directions for multiple locations in GMAP iOS.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps, location

I have an array which contains multiple locations (latitude and longitude).

I plot the locations using the lat and long in map, but I need to join all locations by road as (GET DIRECTIONS IN GOOGLE MAP).

I used google map api in my application.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: This link may help you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the Google Directions API functionality. It allows you to look up directions between multiple points (using waypoints) in order to create one long route. This service requires an API key and has a courtesy limit of 2,500 calls per day.

[Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints)